# What are the PC hardware requirement for developing Cross Platform Applications using .Net MAUI

Tags: visual-studio, maui, .net-maui

I wants to develop cross platform application using .NET MAUI, May I know what will be the PC hardware requirement(Like RAM, Windows Version etc..) to developing Cross Platform Applications using .NET MAUI

Comment: Is this wrong questing was asking for, why I got negative vote for the question, better to suggest or update the question is manner, and if you know the answer very well please do answer and mark for negative.

Comment: Looks like valid question to me. Someone marked it as opinion-based, but that is incorrect. Presumably Microsoft has - or will when finalized - stated specs for the needed software tools. Facts about tools used for programming are on-topic for StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look here https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/preview/

Click: selecting just the componenst needed

In Step 1 ,Check the system requirements.

Here you see what you need for 2022 version. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2022/system-requirements

For Mac https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/mac/installation?view=vsmac-2022

Comment: Also, Maui requires at least Windows 10, 1809 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/supported-platforms

Comment: This answer would be improved by copying in the relevant details. Those links will go dead eventually.